# JMS Serializer: Serialize custom properties of entities

Tags: symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

I want to add a custom property to the serialized entity's representation, which takes an existing entity property and formats it in a user friendly way by using an existing service.

I defined a subscriber class and injected the service used for formatting the existing entity property and subscribed to `serializer.pre_serialize` as follows:

```
class UserSerializationSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $coreTwigExtension;

    private $user;

    public function setCoreTwigExtension(TwigExtension $coreTwigExtension)
    {
        $this->coreTwigExtension = $coreTwigExtension;
    }

    public function setUserService(UserService $user)
    {
        $this->user = $user;
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'event' => 'serializer.pre_serialize', 
                'method' => 'onObjPreSerialize', 
                'class' => 'Some\Bundle\Entity\EntityClass',
                'format' => 'json'
            )
        );
    }

    public function onObjPreSerialize(PreSerializeEvent $event)
    {
        $context = $event->getContext();
        $context->attributes->get('groups')->map(
            function(array $groups) use ($event) {
                if (in_array('somegroup', $groups)) {
                    $obj= $event->getObject();

                    if ($obj->getConfirmedOn()) {
                         $contextualDate = $this->coreTwigExtension->getContextualDate($obj->getConfirmedOn());
                         $event->getVisitor()->addData('displayConfirmedOn', $contextualDate);
                    }
                }
            }
        );
    }
```

}

Subscriber registration:

```
some_bundle.handler.serialization:
    class: Some\Bundle\Handler\ObjectSerializationSubscriber
    calls:
        - [setCoreTwigExtension, ['@bundle_core.twig.extension']]
        - [setUserService, ['@some_bundle.service.user']]
    tags:
        - { name: jms_serializer.event_subscriber }
```

When I serialize an array/collection of entity Some\Bundle\Entity\EntityClass I get the following error:

`There is already data for "displayConfirmedOn".`

How do I resolve this? The only thing stopping me from using `@VirtualProperty` in the entity is that the virtual property output depends on a service, and no dependencies should be injected into an entity.

Comment: After adding data to the visitor in the pre_serialize phase, the added field doesn't appear in the JSON output. From debugging, I see that the data is moved to the dataStack property and data is cleared before putting the object properties in to the data property. I cannot find any documentation regarding this. Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is due to the fact that the entity itself already exposes an attribute `displayConfirmedOn` for serialization. When your event listener runs it is not allowed to add an attribute with the same name to the output and you get this error.

Simply stop exposing the attribute in your entity and then the listener can add a property of the same name.